# SAS when to use OUPUT in datastep

Tags: sas

In the SAS data step, what is the difference between the following code:

```
  DATA MK_RETURN_DATA;
    SET MK_RETURN;
    output;
  RUN;
```

and

```
  DATA MK_RETURN_DATA;
    SET MK_RETURN;
  RUN;
```

Is the output statement absolutely necessary here? (My understanding is, since there is no condition specified, even without the output statement, the output will still be automatically performed.)

Comment: This is a RTFM question. See the section called Details. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here output statement is not at all necessary.
You just have only one output dataset so using the 'output' statement is not required. but if there are more than one output dataset then 'output' statement might come to use..please see the below example

```
data MK_RETURN;
input name :$10. age;
datalines;
Hardik 23
Mishima 47
run;

DATA MK_RETURN_DATA MK_RETURN_DATA2;
    SET MK_RETURN;
    if age= 23 then output MK_RETURN_DATA;
    if age= 47 then output MK_RETURN_DATA2;
  RUN;
```

here the observation with age 23 will go to the MK_RETURN_DATA dataset and the observation with age = 47 will go to the MK_RETURN_DATA2 dataset.

Hope it helps